# Scala Circe infer class

Tags: scala, circe

I'm consuming messages from a websocket. They come in one of two formats:

`{"typ": "subscription", "channel": "BTC-USD"}`

or

`{"typ": "ticker", "price": 10213.42}`

So I have three case classes to use with Circe's decoder:

```
case class GenericMessage(typ: String)

case class SubscriptionMessage(channel: String)

case class TickerMessage(price: Double)
```

How can I have Circe figure out the type of the message, without nesting lots of decode attempts?

```
val message: String = ??? // From websocket
decode[GenericMessage](message) match {
    case Left(e) => ??? // Handle error
    case Right(decoded) => decoded.typ match {
        case "subscription" => decode[SubscriptionMessage](message) match {
            case Left(e) => ??? // Handle error
            case Right(subscriptionMessage) => ??? // Handle subscription message
         }
        case "ticker" =>  decode[TickerMessage](message) match {
            case Left(e) => ??? // Handle error
            case Right(tickerMessage) => ??? // Handle ticker message
         }
        case other => ??? // Handle unrecognized message
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, but when I specify the discriminator like `Configuration.default.withDiscriminator("what_am_i")`, how do I tell it to map value 'ticker' to class TickerMessage, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@LuisMiguelMejiaSuarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez).
I made the following solution using [**circe-generic-extras**](https://users.scala-lang.org/):

```
sealed trait WebSocketMessage
final case class Subscriptions(typ: String, channel: String) extends WebSocketMessage
final case class Ticker(typ: String, price: Double) extends WebSocketMessage

implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default
  .withDiscriminator("type") // Tell circe that the 'type' attribute specifies which case class to decode to
  .copy(transformConstructorNames = _.toLowerCase) // Map 'ticker' string to 'Ticker' class name. Could also pass a more complex mapping function here to use arbitrary class names
  .copy(transformMemberNames = {
      case "typ" => "type" // The word 'type' is a reserved Scala, so class members are renamed to'typ' instead
      case other => Configuration.snakeCaseTransformation(other) // Tell circe to map product_ids field to productIds class member, for example.
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try my Circe ADT extension:
https://github.com/abdolence/circe-tagged-adt-codec

So, in your case it would be:

```scala
sealed trait Message

object Message {

  @JsonAdt("ticker")
  case class Ticker(price : BigDecimal) extends Message

  @JsonAdt("subscription")
  case class Subscription(channel: Channel) extends Message


implicit val encoder : Encoder[Message] = JsonTaggedAdtCodec.createEncoder[Message]("typ")

implicit val decoder : Decoder[Message] = JsonTaggedAdtCodec.createDecoder[Message]("typ")
}
```

PS. I don't recommend using `Double` for money/price types because of the floating point rounding issues.

Comment: Managed to solve with Circe generic dependency but thanks for the tip about doubles